# Break and return inside multiple for-loops with conditional statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, break

I have created a long code, consist of multiple lists inside for-loops. There are nothing wrong with calculation.It does obtain results as it is expected to. The code and construction of lists work fine. The problem is when it runs, I have defined a break when a certain condition is matched. But it does not break at first run, continues and run through all values within range function of first loop. I want to achieve to return a true value, when the condition is matched, and stops and will not keep growing according to range values in first loop.

I would explain how the code would work!

**The code:**
First part is consistent and are inputs

```
import math
import numpy as np


Ned = -500
fcd = 20
fyd = 435
E = 2e5
h = 200
cb = 35
ct = 35
ca = 35
b= 150
y = 12
d = h - cb
ds = ct
a = 25
yb = 8
ecu = 0.0035
rebarnumber = math.floor((b-(2*cb+2*yb+y))/a)
PI_Y2_4 = int(math.pi/4*(y)**2)
disc = []
dis = []
Asi = []
Asci = []
Esc = []
Esci = []
Sc = []
Sci =[]
#############################
# Calculation starts here
#############################

for n in range(0,10):         # <------- First for-loop
    cbb = cb + yb + y/2
    ctt = ct + yb + y/2

    if  0 < n <= rebarnumber:
        Asi.append(PI_Y2_4)
        dis.append( h - cbb)
        Asci.append(PI_Y2_4)
        disc.append( ctt )
    if  rebarnumber < n <= (2 * rebarnumber):
        Asi.append(PI_Y2_4)
        dis.append( h - cbb - ca)
        Asci.append(PI_Y2_4)
        disc.append(cbb + ca)
    if (2*rebarnumber) < n <= (3 * rebarnumber):
        Asi.append(PI_Y2_4)
        dis.append( h - cbb - 2*ca)
        Asci.append(PI_Y2_4)
        disc.append(cbb + 2*ca)
    if (3*rebarnumber) < n <= (4 * rebarnumber):
        Asi.append(PI_Y2_4)
        dis.append( h - cbb - 3*ca)
        Asci.append(PI_Y2_4)
        disc.append(cbb + 3*ca) 
    if (4*rebarnumber) < n <= (5 * rebarnumber):
        Asi.append(PI_Y2_4)
        dis.append( h - cbb - 4*ca)
        Asci.append(PI_Y2_4)
        disc.append(cbb + 4*ca)  
    if (5*rebarnumber) < n <= (6 * rebarnumber):
        Asi.append(PI_Y2_4)
        dis.append( h - cbb - 5*ca)
        Asci.append(PI_Y2_4)
        disc.append(cbb + 5*ca)
    if (6*rebarnumber) < n <= (7 * rebarnumber):
        Asi.append(PI_Y2_4)
        dis.append( h - cbb - 6*ca)
        Asci.append(PI_Y2_4)
        disc.append(cbb + 6*ca)
    if (7*rebarnumber) < n <= (8 * rebarnumber):
        Asi.append(PI_Y2_4)
        dis.append( h - cbb - 7*ca)
        Asci.append(PI_Y2_4)
        disc.append(cbb + 7*ca)

    for i in range(0,len(dis)):
        Esc.insert(i, dis[i])
        Esci.insert(i, disc[i])
        Sc.insert(i, dis[i])
        Sci.insert(i, disc[i])

        for x in np.linspace(1,h,10000):    # <-------- Second for-loop
            for k, _ in enumerate(Esc):
                try:    
                    if x < dis[k]:
                        Esc[k]=( ecu/x*(dis[k]-x) )
                    else:
                        Esc[k]=(- ecu/x*(x-dis[k] ) )

                    if x < disc[k]:
                        Esci[k]=( -ecu/x*(x-disc[k]) )
                    else:
                        Esci[k]=(- ecu/x*(x-disc[k]) )
                except (ZeroDivisionError, RuntimeWarning):
                    Esc[k]=( 0 )
                    Esci[k]=( 0 )       

            for k, _ in enumerate(Sc):       # <-------- Third for-loop
                ss = Esc[k]*E
                if ss <= -fyd:
                    Sc[k]= -fyd
                elif ss >= -fyd and ss < 0:
                    Sc[k]=ss
                else:
                    Sc[k]=min(ss,fyd)

            for k, _ in enumerate(Sci):
                sci = Esci[k]*E
                if sci <= -fyd:
                    Sci[k]= -fyd
                elif sci >= -fyd and sci < 0:
                    Sci[k]=sci
                else:
                    Sci[k]=min(sci,fyd)

            FS = 0
            FSC = 0
            for a, _ in enumerate(Sc):
                FS += Sc[a]*Asi[a]
                FSC+=Sci[a]*Asci[a]

            MS = 0        
            MSC = 0
            for m, _ in enumerate(Sc):
                MS += Sc[a]*Asi[a]*(dis[m]-h/2)
                MSC+= Sci[a]*Asci[a]*(h/2-disc[m])

            Nrd = 0
            Mrd = 0
            Nrd = int((-0.8*x*b*fcd+FSC+FS)/1000)
            Mrd = (0.8*x*b*fcd*(h/2-0.4*x)+MS-MSC)/1000000

            if 0 <= (float(Nrd) - Ned) <= 1:
                print(Nrd, x, Asi)
                break
        break
```

***How does it work?***

First for-loop creates a list with index 0 i.e. `[value1]`, second for-loop makes a x value increment ( range), third for-loops creates lists depend on first created list `[value1]`. then `Nrd` value determines based on increment of x values. if condition `0 <= (float(Nrd) - Ned) <= 1:` is met, then the calculation would stop and return `Nrd` value. if not matched, it goes back and take index 1 from first for-loop, `[value1, value2]` is created, again reach to Nrd if condition is met, would break otherwise continues until it is matched.

My problem is when the code runs, I get those outputs.

```
 Nrd       x             Asi
---------------------------------------------------
-499 181.84938493849384 [113]
-499 162.36533653365336 [113, 113]
-499 147.3990399039904 [113, 113, 113]
-499 137.48784878487848 [113, 113, 113, 113]
-499 130.72117211721172 [113, 113, 113, 113, 113]
-499 126.10391039103911 [113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113]
-499 122.7006700670067 [113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113]
-499 120.01390139013901 [113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113]
-499 119.71537153715371 [113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113]
```

Above outputs are all true mutiple solutions. But I want to stop ( break) by first match, instead of giving all solutions.

I have used `return True`, but it is not really working here, when it complains of being out of function.

Second issue here is second for-loop `for x in np.linspace(1,h,10000):` I really want to run it with many decimals to get a best result, but it slows down and takes long time to calculate. Is there a way to speed up?

Perhaps defining above codelines into functions would work more efficient.

Comment: I think you should try to refactor the multiple if statements at the top, they all look like this `if (k*rebarnumber) < n <= ((k+1)* rebarnumber)`. Additionally you should probably read [the python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Regarding your second issue about speed: Your code seems to solve a math or physics problem. Does it have a name? Can you link to some resource about it? Maybe there is already a library for this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes it is an engineering problem of concrete column with rebars. I do not really think so, there is a library out there for such problems. if there is  then they have it in commercial software.

Comment: How do I achieve refactoring `if (k*rebarnumber) < n <= ((k+1)* rebarnumber)`.

Comment: I refactored your code [here](https://pastebin.com/8m9isEYZ). Also take a look at the other comments.

Comment: Indeed your solution of refactored code is remarkable and very good. I am not a software developer or someone how has studied programming in depth. Frankly I learn much here. Thanks a lot. I would look at it and return if I have any other comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and most straight-forward solution is to move all of your code inside a function

```
 def calculate_results(...args...): # Bad name, use a more suitable one
     ...
     for n in range(0, 10): # <------- First for-loop
         ...
         for x in np.linspace(1,h,10000):    # <-------- Second for-loop
         ...
         if 0 <= (float(Nrd) - Ned) <= 1:
            return Nrd, x, Asi
```

and then call the function afterwards

```
Nrd, x, Asi = calculate_results(...)
print(Nrd, x, Asi)
```

Use a function name that really describes the essence of what the functions is doing and do only that single thing within the function. Then the `return` statement makes it clear that this task is now done.

Comment: I have named the function **mncapacity**, and  that is true, it calculates normalforce and moment capacity of elements.